# How to resolve this error - ValueError: time data did not match format:

Tags: python, datetime

I have a python code where I extract a date string (from a web page) which I then try to convert into a dateobject before using it. It has been working all along but since today I've been getting this error

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19  fmt=%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S
```

This is my code

```
myDate = --get date from user. Example is Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19---
#convert date from string
newDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I've checked the source of the date string and it is still formatted as Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you `import locale; print locale.getdefaultlocale()`?

Comment: This is what I get ('en_US', 'cp1252')

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> myDate = "Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 17, 23, 51, 19)
>>>
```

Are you sure the string is correct? Can you maybe print `repr(myDate)` to be sure?

Comment: If I do print (myDate), I get u'Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19'. I believe the "u'" is from the unicode. If I simply do print(myDate), then I just get Sun, 17 Jul 2011 23:51:19

Comment: I think Tim's question is very important - the locale decides whether "Sun" and "Jul" have any meaning in order to parse them using %a and %b.